# How to run flask project in remote computer server? (windows)

Tags: python, windows, flask, server, remote-server

I uploaded a Flask project that I prepared to a server of a windows computer. I can run the project over localhost on the computer I connect remotely. But I was asked to access the project from any computer with the IP and port address of the remote computer. What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell flask to run on all interfaces, either with:

```
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Or if you're launching via `app.run`, provide the host argument:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Of course if your machine has several interfaces, you could provide the IP of the specific interface instead of `0.0.0.0`.

---

Bear in mind that the dev server is not meant for production.  The above is fine if you want to access you're dev server remotely, but you'll probably want to run with something like gunicorn eventually, in which case provide the `IP:port` combo as the `bind` flag:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app
```